# Using a Trigger in Oracle to Log changes to A Table

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a project for one of my classes. We need to create a log when two of our tables have changes made to them: insert/update/delete. We are required to use Oracle Triggers and PL-SQL. In the log file we need to record the UserID, DateTime, IPAddress, and Event (insert/update/delete). I know how to set up the trigger, but the main problems I have is with the UserID (from logging into a PHP site with the UserID being in a Users table) and more importantly IPAddress. Here is what I have so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_movie_ai
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON Movies
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_username VARCHAR(20);
    v_ipaddress VARCHAR(13);
    v_date NUMBER := FLOOR(SYSDATE);
BEGIN
    SELECT User INTO v_username FROM dual;
    SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') INTO v_ipaddress FROM dual;
    INSERT INTO Logs (USERID, DATETIME, IPADDRESS, EVENT, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (user, v_date, v_ipaddress, 'Movie Created', 'Movie created'));
END;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: THis systable may help you out.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pseudocolumns: uid and user, you can use them in your values clause and the following sql returns the ip address of the client:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual;
```

Comment: I apparently have a syntax error and cannot get this to add to my database. But more importantly, I believe the IP address that this select statement is returning the IP of the server that the Oracle DB is hosted on and not my IP.

Comment: You are wrong. The oracle documentation says the following: IP_ADDRESS IP address of the machine from which the client is connected.

Comment: I am unable to get my trigger to create. Can you help me with whatever syntax error I have created that I am unaware of?

Comment: what is the error message? The order of columns in the values clause is not correct (the second one is datetime but v_username is passed in), datetime cannot be a column name it is a datatype, i cannot see any definition for v_username or v_ipaddress

Comment: Here is the error that I am getting. I don't think that this error is of much help though. If I remove the third variable declare and the third sql execute statement the trigger works fine.
LINE/COL ERROR
8/2  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/82  PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: you have two parentheses at the insert statement

Comment: First, thank you so much for your help. I greatly appreciate it. I have my compile errors fixed. Unfortunately, the username that the 'user' pseudocolumn gives me is the username used to log into the oracle db from the php site, not the user that is logged into the php web page. I have a username and password to connect to the oracle db within my php code. Users have their own userID and password that is being stored in the oracle db to login. The username I want is the username that the clients will use to log into my PHP site. The IP address is that of the server and not the user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5569/discussion-between-user961743-and-steve)