# how to do the following?

Tags: oracle11g

I have two tables Students and courses

how to Create a routine that records deletion activities of users with user name and date of deletion for all tables using triggers..Please help

Comment: What have you tried ? Also, a better title will likely attract better answers.

Comment: its for oracle not for mysql

Comment: These posts may be of some help http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_delete.php  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372320/using-a-trigger-in-oracle-to-log-changes-to-a-table

Answer (score 0):

what ever you want I think you can prepare query for that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) for mysql.

Comment: sorry i m having problem understanding from the above link..can someone please give me the query